# Can a VBA/ADODB recordset connection be used to retreive 'output' parameters from an Access stored query?

Tags: vba, ms-access, adodb

I've been playing with ADODB connections from Excel VBA to both Access and SQL Server data sources.

I can send Input parameters, and also receive Output parameters, when calling SQL Server stored procedures by using the ADODB.Recordset.Parameters collection.

However, while I can send Input parameters to an Access saved query I can't find a way to create or receive the equivalent to an 'Output' parameter from Access.

Does such a mechanism exist using an ADODB connection against an Access database?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, Access does not support output parameters. Maybe return the value through the query if possible?

Comment: You can create an output value in the SELECT clause - and have that "pseudo field" call a VBA function to return a value or "output parameter"

Answer (score 1):

Access save queries do support paramters. You get data back - so no output parmaters.

And to be fair, in most cases even SQL server store procecures do return data as opposed to parmters.

And Access now does have store procedures and table triggers. But these are not callable by ODBC or ADO.

So, you can create a query, and they do support paramters having been added to such queires.

eg:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sales_By_Country [Beginning Date] DateTime, [Ending Date] DateTime;
```

But, don't really let the "PROCEDURE fool you, all it really does is create a saved query with parameters.

Since you don't have nor really can call Access store procedures, then all you really have is SQL statements that you can send to that data engine.

thus, if you need a invoice number?

```
dim ivNum   as long
ivNum = 1234

 strSQL = "SELECT * from tblInvoices WHERE InvoiceNum = " & ivNum
```

So, you in most cases are just as well off to use in-line sql, and that has a big advantage in that y ou don't have pre-define, or even limit your sql query to a fixed or hard coded parameter anyway.